# Can I change Minecraft username?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Purchased Minecraft for my son, and mistakenly used our family name in the account username - I thought "username" was for the Mojang account and that he'd be able to have a different screen name for the game. Can I change that?.

Answer (score 4):

As of today, October 24, 2014, **no**. *However*, [name changes will be implemented in the near future](https://twitter.com/Dinnerbone/status/521968228781006848). I can't tell you exactly *how* soon this will happen, but it is a feature that is in development.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Mojang knowledgebase article](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/928638-minecraft-usernames?b_id=5408) this is not currently possible. You could send them an e-mail and see if they are willing to change it, however.